# Linq Query to match string values in an xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a XML document which looks like

```
<recipes>
<ingredient value"1">APPLE</ingredient>
<ingredient value"2">BANANA</ingredient>
<ingredient value"3">APPLE ORANGE</ingredient>
<ingredient value"4">APPLE BANANA</ingredient>
<ingredient value"5">APPLE STRAWBERRY</ingredient>
<ingredient value"6">GRAPES</ingredient>
</recipes>
```

Now the user inputs some string eg `Apple Grapes Banana`. I sort it alphabetically and try to match it with one of the values by recursively eliminating the last word using string manipulation. But I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this in Linq. I want the query to return the closest match in XML `<ingredient value"4">APPLE BANANA</ingredient>`.

```
string str = "APPLE BANANA GRAPES"; // user input arranged by ascending alphabet and capitalized
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(above xml);// gets above xml
var h = xdoc.Root.Elements("ingredient").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Value == str);//recurse these steps
if (h == null)
{
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(" "));//recurse these steps
}
//check if str matches any value;
//if not remove last word from str and check again;
```

Comment: Please post the LINQ query you've tried so far

Comment: @Amicable I just posted a few lines of codes that are recursed.

Comment: Not sure if useful, but with this algorithm, if a user enters "GRAPEFRUIT GRAPES", no match will be found. Same for "ANYTHING APPLE ORANGE". I would expect that APPLE ORANGE would show up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this :

```
    string str = "APPLE BANANA GRAPES";

    String[] criterias = str.Split(' ');

    XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
    var result =
        x.Root.Elements()
         // count # of matches for each element
         .Select(e => new {e, num = criterias.Count(c => e.Value.Contains(c))}) 
         // order by # of matches, then alphabetically
         .OrderByDescending(r => r.num).ThenBy(r => r.e.Value)
         // get a combination e: XElement, num: # of matches
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit : Not sure if the matching should be a prefix of the search string. Maybe it is more something like this  :

```
        var result =
            x.Root.Elements()
             // get prefixes
             .Where(e => str.StartsWith(e.Value))
             // count matchings
             .Select(e=>new {e, num=e.Value.Split(' ').Length})
             // get max matchings
             .OrderByDescending(r => r.num).ThenBy(r => r.e.Value)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need multiple conditins for closest match here.

For instance
`var h = xdoc.Root.Elements("ingredient").FirstOrDefault(u => str.Contains(u.value))`
 is a condition that would return a nearer value in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple recursive to present

```
    public string FindValueFromText(XDocument xdoc, string str)
    {
        while (str != "")
        {
            var h = xdoc.Root.Elements("ingredient").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Value == str);
            if (h == null)
            {
                str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(" "));
                FindValueFromText(xdoc, str); //recursive
            }
            else 
            {
                return h.Attribute("value").Value;
            }
        }
        return "Not found value";
    }
```

Add these lines where you want to call above method

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
string value = FindValueFromText(xDoc, "APPLE BANANA GRAPES");
```